# all the links redirects to index.php

Tags: php, server

I have a php script. Many of my customers are using it.  But for few they say, they are able to login but when they click on any links from the menu, it just redirects to index.php

I have checked my code, menu links, folders... I have even checked users browser settings, antivirus, firewall... But no problem.

I am not getting why it is happening. here is my session file, while submitting login details i include this file

admin_auth.php

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['ADMIN']))
{
    $_SESSION['name'] = $_SESSION['ADMIN'];

 try {
 $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=nerp', 'root', '');
 } catch(Exception $e) {
  exit('Unable to connect to database.');
 }  

    $m1 = "select * from users where username='".$_SESSION['ADMIN']."'";

    $resultat = $bdd->query($m1) or die(print_r($bdd->errorInfo()));

    //$m2 = mysql_query($m1) or die (mysql_error());
    //$m3 = mysql_fetch_array($resultat);
    $m3 = $resultat->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $_SESSION['uid'] = $m3['id'];
    $_SESSION['name'] = $m3['firstname'] ." ". $m3['lastname'];
    $_SESSION['pos']= $m3['position'];
    $_SESSION['department'] =$m3['department'];
    $_SESSION['location'] =$m3['location'];
    $_SESSION['password'] =$m3['password'];
    $_SESSION['auth'] = md5( date('Ymd') . $_SESSION['password'] );
    $_SESSION['email'] = $m3['email'];
}

else

if(!isset($_SESSION['ADMIN']) )
{

header("location:index.php");
}
```

login_submit.php

```
<?php 
ob_start();
error_reporting(0);
session_start();

include("connect.php");

$user=$_POST['login_name'];
$pass=$_POST['login_password'];


$sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='".$user."' AND password='".$pass."' ";
$query=mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die(mysqli_error());
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($query);
$username=$row['username'];
$count=mysqli_num_rows($query);
if($count==1)

{

$_SESSION['ADMIN']=$row['username'];

$_SESSION['name'] = $row['firstname'];
header("location:dashboard.php?user=".$_SESSION['ADMIN']."");
}
else
{
header("location:index.php");
echo "could not connect";
}
?>
```

is there any problem with this? . if not, why they are not able to open any links.

Comment: Don't see the firewall or antivirus, Just see how the anchor tag is constructed.

Comment: @Sulthan Allaudeen , i did not get. sorry

Comment: What exactly is "$_SESSION['name'] = $_SESSION['name'];" doing?

Comment: Is it possible that after they log in they become inactive for more than 24 minutes (the default $_SESSION timeout), then they click on something and it will not allow them to access it because their session has expired?

Comment: Yes, but immediately after login if they clicks on any other links, it redirects them to index.php. how it is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based your code, and the symptom you described of those few users, it looks like those few users have disallowed cookies.  So when a user with cookies disallowed goes to make a subsequent request after authenticating, they don't send the PHPSESSID cookie (here you can see an example)[image: PHPSESSID]

So, what happens in your code is, the server sees isset($_SESSION['ADMIN']) is *not* set, and it drops them to the bottom of your code, which sends them back to index.php.

You can test this by disallowing cookies in your browser.  A way to fix it (other than telling your users to enable cookies) is to attach some kind of ID to the URL and maintain an ID as your users move though the site.  PHP can do this for you if you set:

```
<?php
     ini_set("session.use_cookies",1);
     ini_set("session.use_only_cookies",0);
     ini_set("session.use_trans_sid",1);
     session_start();
?>
```

Although I should mention this works with regular html links.  It works by the PHP preprocessor adding its code to your links.  Since you mentioned a menu, if your menu links are generated by javascript the PHP preprocessor won't know to add its code to the links there.

Comment: Thank you very much for this. It worked for me. I have been trying to solve this from last 3 days. Thanks a ton.